# Javascript Loop / Array / Variable question

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to get this to work and I hope this isn't too vague.    -Chris

```
var example = new Array();

var test1 = "one";
var test2 = "two";
var test3 = "three";

for (v = 1; v <= 3; v++) {
    alert(example[test + v])
}
```

I want the alert to say:

> one
>   two
>   three

Comment: do you want a single alert to say "one two three" or 3 alerts to say "one" then "two" then "three" ?

Comment: I'm not faulting you for not knowing the basics, we are all at different levels here, but I would suggest quickly going through the tutorial at http://www.w3schools.com/js/ and get some of the basics under your belt before asking questions. There is a section on there about arrays as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array `example` isn't initialized anywhere. It should be like this:

```
var example = new Array();
example[1] = "one";
example[2] = "two";
example[3] = "three";

for (v = 1; v <= 3; v++) {
    alert(example[v]);
}
```

This will make three separate alerts that say "one", then "two", then "three". If you want a single alert that says "one two three", you should do:

```
var example = new Array();
example[1] = "one";
example[2] = "two";
example[3] = "three";

var output = "";

for (v = 1; v <= 3; v++) {
    output += " " + example[v];
}

alert(output);
```

### In response to Chris' request for follow-up:

In that case you could nest the loops, but it would be much more efficient to generate the output string once and then loop to display it. Example:

```
var output = "";
// This variable just makes it happen 3 times, it no longer corresponds to the array size
for (numAlerts = 1; numAlerts  <= 3; numAlerts ++) {

    // This is the actual index for the array
    for (v = 1; v <= example.length; v++) {
        output += " " + example[v];
    }
    alert(output);

    // Clean out the string or it will keep concatenating
    output = "";
}
```

That example has computational cost of ***n^2*** (technically ***m x n***), because you are nesting the loops. To make 3 alerts, each with the concatenation of 3 array elements, would take 9 significant operations. The next example:

```
var output = "";
// This variable is once more for array size
for (v = 1; v <= example.length; v++) {
    output += " " + example[v];
}

// This variable controls how many times the alert is printed
for (numAlerts = 1; numAlerts <= 3; numAlerts++) {    
    alert(output);
}
```

This one has computational cost ***2n***, reduced to ***n***. In our example, 6 significant actions occur, 3 to concatenate the string, and 3 more to print it. 6 < 9, but not by much. However, imagine you have 300 items in the list, and want to print it 1000 times. Well, now 1300 << 300000.

**One last note:** in most languages, arrays are zero-based, so it would be `example[0], [1], [2], etc.` I understand you matched `example[1] = "one"` but it will make loops confusing if you start at 1. The standard `for` cycle for an array is:

```
var example = ["zero", "one", "two", "three"];
for (i = 0; i < example.length; i++) {
    action(example[i]);
}
```

Comment: @Chris Chiera: You can initialize the array using an array-literal too. `["one", "two", "three"];` would give you the same array in a single line of code.

Comment: Hey guys I have one more question. How would this work if I wanted the output to say:
one, two, three
one, two, three
one, two, three
one, two, three

Comment: Andy: Thanks again for your help. This will give me something to study for the next week! Cheers!